# Dual Boot - Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub

I have just set up a dual boot machine by performing the following steps:

1. Enable UEFI in the bios
2. Install Windows 10
3. Install Ubuntu
4. Configure GRUB2 to let me select OS on boot

All good so far, but I guarantee that the moment I boot Windows it will modify the boot sequence and ONLY boot windows

How do I stop Windows 10 from modifying my GRUB config?

Comment: Try disable secure boot. It enabled with Ubuntu it does/should work, but in my experience it's really designed for Windows.

Try to disable fast startup: https://hackernoon.com/installing-ubuntu-18-04-along-with-windows-10-dual-boot-installation-for-deep-learning-f4cd91b58557

Comment: The last few versions of Windows 10, from v. 1803 on, have been less likely to mangle dual boot. BTW, Secure Boot works well with Ubuntu, but *not* Fast Boot in BIOS/Wndows, because that boots from the last active OS!

Comment: What you're fearful of rarely if ever happens with dual-boot in UEFI. What sometimes happens, for obvious reasons, is Windows feature updates changing the boot order from "Ubuntu" (Grub) to "Windows" but users can change it back easily. The reason the Windows update does that Is the need for multiple reboots, it's not an evil conspiracy against Linux.

Comment: I Use "EasyBCD" to manage my multi boot setup Ubuntu windows 10 and windows 7 and I never had any issues....give it a try and you wont need to disable secure boot.